# Training multiple models in series in Keras for hyperparameter optimization

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

The idea is to train multiple models using the same training dataset, changing some parameters each time in order to see which parameter works best. In order to do so I would need every model to be trained from scratch every time.

My current code (simplified) is:

```
scores= []

for i in range(n):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(...)
    model.compile(...)
    model.fit(...)
    scores.append([i, model.score(...)])

for score in scores:
    print(score)
```

It runs as expected printing:

```
[0, 0.89712456798]
[1, 0.76652347349]
[2, 0.83178943210]
...
```

but I can't understant if the code does what described above or if, on the contrary, trains models that depend each on the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call

```
model = Sequential()
```

your model is re-initialized, so the code sketch above does indeed what you want it to do, i.e. fitting a new model from scratch for each loop iteration.

Comment: Great! Thanks desertnaut for the super prompt answer. Does running this code with a large number of parameters (training a large number of models) over and over affect the training speed? I there something (memory issues etc...) that poses a limit to the theorical number of iterations?

Comment: @leo nothing that I am aware of - have used similar loops myself (although not for hyperparameter tuning but for statistical assessment of performance).

Comment: In my experience, changing the numbers of nodes in the hidden layers or batch size, affects the training speed. But depends on your CPU and GPU of course.

Comment: @PySeeker you seem to have misunderstood OP"s question; of course batch size and model size affect the training time in general, but this was not the question here, which was about "*(training a large number of models) over and over*"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. It creates each time a new model.

But I would suggest to train multiple model in prallel. I just discovered RayLib, which is well suited for this task.

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_hyperparameter.html

Your code with 4 parallel training sessions, with 5 iterations each:

```
import ray

@ray.remote
def train(sequence):
    scores= []
    for i in range(sequence)
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(...)
        model.compile(...)
        model.fit(...)
        scores.append([i, model.score(...)])
    return scores

n=4
results = []
for i in range(n):
    results.append(train.remote(5))

results_data = ray.get(results)

for i in results_data:
    print(i)
```

You could make hyperparameter as an input in your train function and test different architectures fast. 
RayLib requires Ubuntu tho.